# Foreign Key mismatch error in sqlite when trying to use rowid as foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple two table relationships. Member, which can contain 0 or more Characters.

Here is the scheme:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'main'.'member' (
    'id'    TEXT NOT NULL,
    'platform_id'   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY('id', 'platform_id')
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'main'.'character' (
    'id'    TEXT NOT NULL,
    'member_rowid'  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY('id', 'member_rowid'),
    FOREIGN KEY ("member_rowid")
       REFERENCES member ("rowid")
       ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I then insert a member like so:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE into member ('id', 'platform_id') VALUES ("mid", 1);
select rowid from member;
```

which shows the rowid of 1.

However, when I try to insert into Character like so:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE into character ('id', 'member_rowid') VALUES ("cid", 1);
```

I get the following error:

```
Result: foreign key mismatch - "character" referencing "member"
At line 1:
INSERT OR IGNORE into character ('id', 'member_rowid') VALUES ("cid", 1);
```

Its not clear to me what is going on, since the rowid exists. Can I not use rowid as a foreign key?

I have seen some discussion around a foreign key having to reference the "entire primary key or unique key/index". I thought rowid satisfied that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kFirst, you are using single quotes for identifiers.  I strongly, strongly discourage you from doing this -- even if SQLite allows it.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Second, your foreign key is just really weird.  It is sad that SQLite accepts it.  The foreign key should be to the *primary key*.  You can specify that `rowid` is the primary key -- fine.  Then the other keys should be declared as `unique`.

Finally, the code you have works when I try it.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0963c1b8a497cd432fc8740e3efde451) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. If i have a table with a combo primary key, can I have another table use it as a foreign key? In the case of member, the combo of member_id, platform_id are unique. I don't know why its not working on my system, but Ill see if I can get it working based on your feedback.

Comment: @mikechambers . . . That is called a *composite primary key*.  I prefer synthetic keys (a single numeric key); however, you can use both keys -- but you need to define both in each table that uses them for a foreign reference.